# Does submodularity provide guarantees for "backwards" greedy elimination algorithms?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, algorithms

The submodularity condition, besides having a definition that "makes sense," is also nice because it offers guarantees for the maximum coverage problem (as well as the related set cover problem, and the subset selection problem in statistics). It guarantees that the greedy forward selection algorithm is within $1-1/e$ of the optimum. Does this condition also provide guarantees for the greedy backward elimination algorithm?

If so, how does the two guarantees compare?

If not, what exactly about the submodularity condition makes it poorly suited toward providing guarantees to the greedy backward algorithm? And what sort of conditions are more appropriate for analyzing greedy backward elimination?

The "forward greedy" algorithm (also called the stepwise forward variable selection method in statistics) [described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm), consists of iteratively adding elements based on how much they improve the optimization criteria, until one has reached the given maximum number of steps.

The "backward greedy" algorithm consists of iteratively removing elements based on how much their removal worsens the optimization criteria, until one has reached the desired number of remaining elements.

Comment: Consider defining your terms so nobody has to guess the specific problem you're solving or the algorithm you're talking about.

Comment: @MishaLavrov -- thanks for the feedback. Let me know if my edits were helped clarify.